# R: Loop through list to compare column names and create new fields in data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, purrr

I flattened json data using `jsonlite` and added up with some exotic columns names.  See the sample data below:

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,2,3,4))
df$`events.location.John.round.1` = 
list(list("A","B","C"),list("B","C","E"),list("A","C"),list("D","E","B"))
df$`events.location.John.round.2` = 
list(list("A","D","E"),NA,list("B","C"),list("B","E","C"))
df$`events.location.Mary.round.1` = list(NA,NA,list("B","C"),list("E","A"))
df$`events.location.Mary.round.2` = list(list("A","B","E"),NA,list("B","A"),list("D","E","C"))

LocationList <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
PersonList <- c("John", "Mary")
```

I'd like to loop through my lists of locations and people to generate new variables in my data frame. Here's some sample output:

```
df$`NumLocationsJohnRound1` = c(3,3,2,3)
df$`NumLocationsMaryRound1` = c(0,0,2,2)
df$`B.JohnRound1` = c(1,1,0,1)
df$`B.MaryRound1` = c(0,0,1,0)
```

In English, the first operation would be "for each person in PersonList, find column names containing the person's name and possibly other text, and return the length of that cell's list"

The second operation would be "for each person in PersonList, find column names containing the person's name, and create a new binary field, *for each location in LocationList*, with 1 if that column contains that location.

Basically all new variables I need either apply a function to the matching column, or search a list in the cell for a certain value.  The key here is a flexible method of iterating over a list, finding columns by name, and producing new columns named based on the list.

I think the solution depends on `Regex/grep()`, but I don't know how to insert list items into a Regex string (perhaps with `paste`?). `select(contains())` could be one of the steps.

The solution likely involes `purrr::map()`, `dplyr::mutate()`, or possibly a custom function involving these.  I'd like to avoid being entirely dependent on for loops.

I know this is a challenging question.  Insight into any piece of it (how to find columns containing a list item in their name, how to create new columns with names based on list items, how to search list-columns) would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear, but based on the 'Numlocations' output, may be this would help

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
nm1 <- sub("events", "Num", names(df)[-1])
df[nm1] <-  df[-1] %>% 
                  map(., ~lengths(.) *map_lgl(., ~ !all(is.na(.))))
```

For the second part, we can get the binary output with `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
nm2 <-rep(paste0(names(df)[2:5], sub("events.location", "", names(df)[2:5])), each = 5) 
df[nm2] <- df[2:5] %>% 
                map(mtabulate) %>% 
                bind_cols
```

---

Or this can all be done within the chain

```
nm3 <- sub("events.location", "", names(df)[2:5])
df[-1] %>%
  map_df(., ~lengths(.) *map_lgl(., ~ !all(is.na(.)))) %>% 
           rename_all(~nm1) %>%
           bind_cols(df, ., 
             df[-1] %>%
               map(., ~map(., ~factor(., levels = LETTERS[1:5]))) %>% 
               map(~as.data.frame.matrix(table(melt(.)[2:1]))) %>% 
               map2(., nm3, ~setNames(.x,  paste0(names(.x), .y))))
```

giving the output

```
#ID events.location.John.round.1 events.location.John.round.2 events.location.Mary.round.1 events.location.Mary.round.2 Num.location.John.round.1
#1  1                      A, B, C                      A, D, E                           NA                      A, B, E                         3
#2  2                      B, C, E                           NA                           NA                           NA                         3
#3  3                         A, C                         B, C                         B, C                         B, A                         2
#4  4                      D, E, B                      B, E, C                         E, A                      D, E, C                         3
#  Num.location.John.round.2 Num.location.Mary.round.1 Num.location.Mary.round.2 A.John.round.1 B.John.round.1 C.John.round.1 D.John.round.1 E.John.round.1
#1                         3                         0                         3              1              1              1              0              0
#2                         0                         0                         0              0              1              1              0              1
#3                         2                         2                         2              1              0              1              0              0
#4                         3                         2                         3              0              1              0              1              1
#  A.John.round.2 B.John.round.2 C.John.round.2 D.John.round.2 E.John.round.2 A.Mary.round.1 B.Mary.round.1 C.Mary.round.1 D.Mary.round.1 E.Mary.round.1 A.Mary.round.2
#1              1              0              0              1              1              0              0              0              0              0              1
#2              0              0              0              0              0              0              0              0              0              0              0
#3              0              1              1              0              0              0              1              1              0              0              1
#4              0              1              1              0              1              1              0              0              0              1              0
#  B.Mary.round.2 C.Mary.round.2 D.Mary.round.2 E.Mary.round.2
#1              1              0              0              1
#2              0              0              0              0
#3              1              0              0              0
#4              0              1              1              1
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `dplyr` and `purrr`

First, use `mutate_at` to calculate the length of list for all columns beginning with "events".

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("events")), funs(`Len` = map(., ~length(.x[!is.na(.x)]))))
```

After that, design a function to report the binary outcome. Apply that function to all the elements in `LocationList`. Store the result in `loc_results`.

```
match_fun <- function(Location, df){
  df2 <- df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("events")), 
              funs(!!Location := map_int(., ~as.integer(Location %in% unlist(.x))))) %>%
    select(ID, contains("_"))
  return(df2)
}

loc_results <- map(LocationList, match_fun, df = df)
```

Finally, merge all data frame in `loc_results` to be `df3`, and then join `df2` and `df3` to be `df4`. `df4` is the final output.

```
df3 <- reduce(loc_results, left_join, by = "ID")
df4 <- df2 %>% left_join(df3, by = "ID")
```

This solution considers the naming convention. Below is the resulting data frame. As you can see, columns ended with `_Len` show the length of list, while columns ended with `_A`, `_B`, `_C`, `_D`, and `_E` show the binary outcome.

```
df4

  ID events.location.John.round.1 events.location.John.round.2 events.location.Mary.round.1 events.location.Mary.round.2
1  1                      A, B, C                      A, D, E                           NA                      A, B, E
2  2                      B, C, E                           NA                           NA                           NA
3  3                         A, C                         B, C                         B, C                         B, A
4  4                      D, E, B                      B, E, C                         E, A                      D, E, C
  events.location.John.round.1_Len events.location.John.round.2_Len events.location.Mary.round.1_Len events.location.Mary.round.2_Len
1                                3                                3                                0                                3
2                                3                                0                                0                                0
3                                2                                2                                2                                2
4                                3                                3                                2                                3
  events.location.John.round.1_A events.location.John.round.2_A events.location.Mary.round.1_A events.location.Mary.round.2_A
1                              1                              1                              0                              1
2                              0                              0                              0                              0
3                              1                              0                              0                              1
4                              0                              0                              1                              0
  events.location.John.round.1_B events.location.John.round.2_B events.location.Mary.round.1_B events.location.Mary.round.2_B
1                              1                              0                              0                              1
2                              1                              0                              0                              0
3                              0                              1                              1                              1
4                              1                              1                              0                              0
  events.location.John.round.1_C events.location.John.round.2_C events.location.Mary.round.1_C events.location.Mary.round.2_C
1                              1                              0                              0                              0
2                              1                              0                              0                              0
3                              1                              1                              1                              0
4                              0                              1                              0                              1
  events.location.John.round.1_D events.location.John.round.2_D events.location.Mary.round.1_D events.location.Mary.round.2_D
1                              0                              1                              0                              0
2                              0                              0                              0                              0
3                              0                              0                              0                              0
4                              1                              0                              0                              1
  events.location.John.round.1_E events.location.John.round.2_E events.location.Mary.round.1_E events.location.Mary.round.2_E
1                              0                              1                              0                              1
2                              1                              0                              0                              0
3                              0                              0                              0                              0
4                              1                              1                              1                              1
```